# filter div by indexOf of classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I need help to filter a ton of populated divs with dynamically filled class names

this is a form to that when a option selected needs to hide all divs that do NOT  have an indexOf the class name of the div

```
    <p>To narrow down the results, fill out the form below.</p>

    <!-- FORM -->
    <strong>Student/Teacher</strong>
    <select name="classification" id="classification">
        <option value="" selected>Select...</option>
        <option value="student">Student</option>
        <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <strong>Education Level</strong>
    <select name="level" id="level">
        <option selected>Select...</option>
        <option value="elementary">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="middle">Middle School</option>
        <option value="high">High School</option>
        <option value="college">College</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <strong>STEM Subject</strong>
    <select name="subject" id="subject">
        <option selected>Select...</option>
        <option value="science">Science</option>
        <option value="technology">Technology</option>
        <option value="engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    </select> 
    <br /><br />
    <strong>Resource Type</strong>
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option selected>Select...</option>
        <option value="sa">Scholarships & Awards</option>
        <option value="as">Academics Support</option>
        <option value="is">Industry Spotlights</option>
        <option value="ce">Career Exploration</option>
        <option value="cs">Career Spotlight</option>
        <option>Professional Organization Resource</option>   
    </select>             
    <br /><br />

    <div class="studentelementaryscienceas">
    <!-- text here -->
    </div>
```

the div will be cycled dynamically with different class names... 100's of div's looped into and injected with a set class name provided by the database ex: teachermiddletechnologysa

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('#classification').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "student" & (this.className.indexOf(val) > -1)){
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'student'"]').show();
    }
    else {
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'teacher'"]').show();
    }
});
<!-- the rest is not exact just shorthand -->
$('#level').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "elementary" & (this.className.indexOf(val) > -1)){
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'elementary'"]').show();
        }
    else {
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'middle'"]').show();
});

$('#subject').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "science" & (this.className.indexOf(val) > -1)){
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'science'"]').show();
        }
    else {
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'technology'"]').show();
});

$('#type').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "as" & (this.className.indexOf(val) > -1)){
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'as'"]').show();
        }
    else {
        $('div').hide();
        $('div[class$="'sa'"]').show();
});


</script>
```

Comment: Check your statements again, `& != &&`

Comment: Also those strings aren't formatted properly, see the syntax highlighting? I suggest you check your code for errors before posting. This will help you http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems

- As @elclanrs said `&` != `&&`
- The attribute selector you are using is ends with is wrong as the match can be found anywhere
- Also the combined class selector you are using might produce unexpected results. Why can't you have the class for the div as `<div class="student elementary science as"></div>`
- Your string concatenation(`$('div[class$="'as'"]').show();`) is syntactically wrong, it should be `$('div[class$="' + as +'"]').show();`

Try

```
var $divs = $('div');
var $filters = $('#classification, #level, #subject, #type').change(function () {
    var filter = $filters.map(function () {
        return this.value && this.value.indexOf('Select...') == -1 ? '[class*=' + this.value + ']' : undefined;
    }).get();
    $divs.hide()
    if (filter.length) {
        $divs.filter(filter.join('')).show()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nst2R/)

---

If you can separate the class names like `<div class="student elementary science as"></div>`  then

```
var $divs = $('div');
var $filters = $('#classification, #level, #subject, #type').change(function () {
    var filter = $filters.map(function () {
        return this.value && this.value.indexOf('Select...') == -1 ? '.' + this.value : undefined;
    }).get();
    $divs.hide()
    if (filter.length) {
        $divs.filter(filter.join('')).show()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DQtpq/)

Comment: I can change it to have multiple classes like what you mentioned: <div class="student elementary science as"></div>, but how would that change the js? And Thank You so much for the super quick response!